# Is there a way not to stop progress bar while waiting for data from an API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, loading

I am using vuejs and nprogress (displays a progress line on top of the page). I want the progress line to move while i am waiting to load data from an API.

```
async created() {
    NProgress.configure({ trickleSpeed: 30 });
    NProgress.start();
    try {
      this.results = await this.getResults(this.resultsApi);
    } catch (err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
    NProgress.done();
},
methods: {
    getResults(url) {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        return res;
      } catch (err) {
        return err;
      }
    }
}
```

While waiting for the data to load, the progress line stops, but i want it to not stop moving.

Comment: Well what does `getResults()` do?

Comment: You can call `NProgress.done() ` whenever required which will stop the progressbar

Comment: @MunnaBhakta the OP wants to **not** stop the progress bar.

Comment: i added getResults() to the code..

Comment: If you remove the call to `NProgress.done()`, does the progress bar move? I know that isn't what you want but it would help to confirm that the call to `start` did actually do something.

Comment: It moves the same as before and stops when it gets to the await function, and continuos after it.

Answer (score 0):

There is this `inc()` function you can use but for as from the [documentation](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress#advanced-usage)

> Incrementing: To increment the progress bar, just use .inc(). This
>   increments it with a random amount. This will never get to 100%: use
>   it for every image load (or similar).
>
> NProgress.inc();

But for that you can to call this again and again to keep the bar moving until data loads. Sort of a loop to `increment` arbitrary value to progress bar

Comment: I know this, but is there a way to trigger this while waiting for the data? I know i could do this, ig there would be more API calls, but here I have just one.

Comment: Just like i said, have to create something of your own. start an `interval` of `1 sec` and call `NProgress.inc()` in it and when all the API calls are done just clear the `interval`

Comment: @DavidSklansky Try [axios `onDownloadProgress`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)?